# Is it possible for Nodejs to read the system logs of a connected device via a web application?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, adb

I am looking for a way to read the system logs of a connected device via a web application.  Basically, I want the user to be able to connect their iphone, android, tablet etc and be able to see what is occurring on their device at the system/consoleLog level.  Similar to adb logcat.  This would be a via a web application and not on software installed locally.  Is this feasible using react/nodejs?  What technologies should I consider using?

Answer (score 1):

There're several components you need for achieving this.

Backend

- File Monitoring (Native Node.js `fs.watch`)
- Real-time update ([Socket.io](https://socket.io/))

Frontend

- Any framework you're comfortable with, I'm using React.js with socket.io client

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I'm already using socket.io and react on this project so i'm glad those are the options you recommended.  I'm curious how fs.watch gains access to the device level events? Would the device have to be writing to a file and nodeJS watching that file?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible, but in a very limited sense.

Your users will be required to manually upload their log files to your web application.

You can "ask" them to do this by using the FileReader api in javascript. Here is a [demo page](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader).

As you can see you must manually select a file to be uploaded and give the website. To programmatically set the path of a log file and try to call it without the user noticing is not possible.

The reason for this is anything you make that is served via a web application will run in the sandbox of the users browser.

For obvious security reasons a browser won't let random websites read/write to local files of a persons phone without explicit permission.

Node.js won't help you here because in order to use the functions Node.js has such as accessing local system files the app would have to be installed locally and not running in a "browsers sandbox".

I hope this helps. If you want more examples of the filereader api let me know and I can write something up for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I was hoping to allow users to see what is occurring in near real time on their device and filter out specific data that is relevant to them.  Based on your response, I'm guessing this may not be possible as they need to upload an already completed log file?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah what you are trying to do would be much better suited for a native application. However if you were okay with the user granting access to a log file once every time they open your website you can read that file 100 times over without asking for permission again until they close your website.